# hide a message after 3 seconds and my code displaying multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running an ajax call and when i try to submit, my input field gets an another div underneath it and shows error, but if i click the button too many times, it keeps on adding new messages one under the another

and also i want to hide the message after 3 seconds

so basically two problems in my code

```
$.ajax({
            url : $('##frm').attr('data-action'),
            type: 'post',
            data: $('##frm').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.indexOf("emailissue") > -1) {
                    $("##emailaddress").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;font-size:0.90em;'>Please Provide valid email address</div>");
                    $('##validation').delay(3000).fadeOut();
                }else{
                    $("##ID").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
                    $("##ID").css('display','none');
                }
             }
        });
```

html is like this

```
<div class="form-group">
                      <label for="emailaddress">We are missing you email, please enter below</label>
                      <input type="text" name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" placeholder="Enter your email" class="form-control">
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a static response element in the DOM:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="emailaddress">We are missing your email, please enter it below</label>
  <input type="text" name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" placeholder="Enter your email" class="form-control">
  <div id="response" class="validation"></div>
</div>
```

Then in the response from your ajax call, update the contents and visibility of the `#response` element:

```
if (data.indexOf("emailissue") > -1) 
{
  $("#response").show().text('Please Provide a valid email address');
  setTimeout(function(){
      $('#response').fadeOut();
  }, 3000);
}
```

By toggling between hiding/showing the `#response` element, we no longer need to worry about additional response elements being added, or deleting older ones.

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/uz3enwjp/) I made. Click the "Test" button to the right to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have double '##' when you try to select the element?

Also after 3 second you need to remove the new created div from the DOM,

it's not enough to just call the `fadeOut()` (my guess it's just set opacity 0)